# K means lib spark python

Tags: python, apache-spark, k-means, lib

I'm trying to implement the kmean algorithm for spark using python, I'm using the python code located in the library http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#k-means
the code is working but in order to make the plot I need to manipulate the object in "sameModel = KMeansModel.load(sc, "KMeansModel2")", I don't know how to do it.. should I load sc in csv file ? help please!

```
  from __future__ import print_function
  # $example on$
  from numpy import array
  from math import sqrt
  # $example off$
  from pyspark import SparkContext
  # $example on$
  from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel
  # $example off$
  if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="KMeansExample")  # SparkContext
    # $example on$
    # Load and parse the data
    data = sc.textFile("kmeans_data2.txt")
    parsedData = data.map(lambda line: array([float(x) for x in      line.split(' ')]))
    # Build the model (cluster the data)
    clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, 2, maxIterations=10,    initializationMode="random")
    # Evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors
    def error(point):
        center = clusters.centers[clusters.predict(point)]
        return sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in (point - center)]))
WSSSE = parsedData.map(lambda point: error(point)).reduce(lambda x,y:x + y)
    print("Within Set Sum of Squared Error = " + str(WSSSE))
    # Save and load model
    clusters.save(sc, "KMeansModel2")
    sameModel = KMeansModel.load(sc, "KMeansModel2")
    print (sameModel)
    # $example off$
    sc.stop()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the mode (predict) you need to do it within a running spark context (e.g. you can [set it up in a jupyter notebook](https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f) )